# Javascript error on reputation page when there are no changes to show

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, error-message

Looking at my own reputation page on Maths StackExchange with no records to show.

Message: 'reputationView' is undefined
Line: 1
Char: 5665
Code: 0
URI: http://sstatic.net/js/user-page.js?v=fb07c6493c2d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fair enough; that'll be fixed next deploy.